# javascript add data to a json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i am working with angularJS and im pretty newbie. So i have a variable in the controller scope which looks like this.

```
$scope.emptyContact = {'contact_firstname':'', 'contact_lastname':''};
```

and i want to use this to reset the `newContact` json which i use to add data with a form. But when i do this:

```
$scope.newContact = $scope.emptyContact;
```

when i change something in the `newContact` variable, it also changes into `emptyContact` variable. Is there a way to give `newContact` variable the values from `emptyContact` without 'binding' their datas together ?
Thank you, Daniel!

Comment: Use: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That's happening because the reference to object is keept

```
a = {};     // a will be an empty object
b = a;      // b will be a (the reference is kept)
a === b     // return true
b.c = 12;   // set c key to b
a.c         // returns 12 because b is a and c is set to a, too

d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)); // clone a 
a === d                            // return false because d is not a
d.e = 13;                          // sets e key as 13
a.e                                // returns undefined because d is NOT a
```

So, I always prefer to use `obj1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1))` to clone an object.

Your code becomes:

```
$scope.newContact = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.emptyContact));
```

or using [angular.copy()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy):

```
angular.copy($scope.emptyContact, $scope.newContact);
```

...and your `emptyContact` will not be changed.

Comment: thank you very much, i will use the copy function from angular

Comment: @PacuraruDaniel Send me your email address using my contact form from my SO profile and we will can talk more. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$scope.newContact = $scope.emptyContact;
```

to:

```
angular.copy($scope.emptyContact, $scope.newContact);
```

see: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy

**Explanation below:**

In Javascript, when you assign one object to another, you are actually passing a reference, so both variables are actually referring to the same object.

Here is an example from a NodeJS repl:

```
> a = {'msg': 'hello'}
{ msg: 'hello' }
> b = a
{ msg: 'hello' }
> b.count = 50
50
> a
{ msg: 'hello', count: 50 }
>
```

In the above example, the reference from `a` is copied to `b`, to both `a` and `b` then point to the same *value*.

If you want to be able to change `b` without affecting `a`, you will need to make a *clone* of `a` instead of just copying the reference. Here is one way to do it:

```
b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))
```

with an example from the Node repl:

```
> a = {'msg': 'bye'}
{ msg: 'bye' }
> b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))
{ msg: 'bye' }
> b
{ msg: 'bye' }
> b.count = 55
55
> a
{ msg: 'bye' }
> b
{ msg: 'bye', count: 55 }
>
```

**AngularJS** actually has its own implementation of doing this, see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy, which is what you should actually use when working with AngularJS.

Comment: this is great, thank you so much for this. i will use the copy from angular :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.emptyContact = function(){
    this.contact_firstname ='';
    this.contact_lastname = ''
};
$scope.newContact = new $scope.emptyContact();
```

This way you can create new objects from emptyContact.

Answer (score 0):

**Cloning** the Object will help you to achieve this

please have a look on following link

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)